# How to attach a jQuery event to a grid view that is not visible on document ready?

Tags: jquery, gridview, asp.net-2.0

I am trying to hook into a link in a gridview with jquery but the grid is in an update panel and not visible until the user runs a report. If I add the class ".myLink" to any other "a" tag it works fine, but as the gridview is not there at document.ready I am not sure where to call this from

```
              $(document).ready(function(){
                $('a .myLink').click(function(){
                  var link = $(this).attr('href');
                  alert(link);
                  return false;
                });
              });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to handle events on element created at any time, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a .myLink').live('click', function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(link);
    return false;
  });
});
```

If you have the container that it'll appear in, and it *doesn't* get replaced, you can use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to be more efficient, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#containerID').delegate('a .myLink', 'click', function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(link);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Both of these were working great, but I went with the .delegate as there could be a change of a link outside of this GV that has the same class and would not want this JS to run. The .delegate lets me attach to only the tags in this panel.  Thanks again -

Comment: This is not deprecated. Use event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at jQuery.live().

http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a .myLink').live('click', function(){
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(link);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.live()` method is able to affect elements that have not yet been added to the DOM through the use of event delegation.

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/live/)