# JQuery how to click div inside li to update another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a ul i am appending li's with two div's through JavaScript to it, shown as below

```
c_list = $('.encounter_creatures_list > ul')  
db.transaction(
    function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql(
          'SELECT * FROM creatures;',
          [], 
            function (transaction, result) {
               var creature_array = new Array();
               for (i=0; i < result.rows.length; i++){
                 var row = result.rows.item(i)
               li = $("li[key='" + row.id + "']")
                     if(li.length > 0) {
                       // $('#name', li).html(encounter.name)
                     } else {
                      creature_array.push(row)
                       var counter = 0
                           li = $("<li key='"+ row.id + "' class='list_"+ row.id + "'>"+ row.name +  "<div class='plus_"+ row.id + "'>+</div> <div class='counter_"+ row.id + "'>"+ counter  +"</div></li>") 
                       li.css({'border': '1px solid #999999', 'color': '#222222', 'display': 'block', 'font-size': '17px', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'margin-bottom': '-0.5px', 'padding': '12px 10px', 'text-decoration': 'none'})
                       c_list.append(li)      
 //                           alert($(".counter_"+ row.id + "", li).text()) 
//                           $(".plus_"+ row.id + "", li).click(function(event) {
//                              $(".counter_"+ row.id + "", li).text(counter + 1)
//                             event.preventDefault();
//                           })

                    } 
               } 
            })
       })
```

I want to do the part which i have commented, i.e. clicking one div to update another inside li.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493041/how-to-attach-a-jquery-event-to-a-grid-view-that-is-not-visible-on-document-ready/4493094#4493094

Comment: ~ I appreciate that you want to figure out how to do this, but something here is just a little convoluted. Do you really need something this complex to do what you're trying? ~ Additionally, have you heard of the live command? Also, are you pushing the query from the client to the server?

Comment: Yes i am  pushing the query from the client to the server, i know live command in jQuery, but i tried that also, can you explain in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Add another class to the div that is static. Than add this to your onload event. All elements with the class .classname will have the onclick functionality.

```
$(".classname").live("click", function() {
  var rowid = $(this).attr("key");
  alert($(".counter_"+ rowid, li).text());
  $(".counter_"+ rowid, li).text(counter + 1);
});
```

One side note. Your code is a bit messy. You should try to refactor it a bit.